# Kendo Sortable + Karma: unit testing hint function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have an existing case for kendo sortable and I'm trying to test the hint function using karma and jasmine. Any ideas on how to emulate the drag event with Kendo Sortable so that the hint function is called?

```
$element.find("#sortable-container").kendoSortable({
    axis: "none",
    cursor: "move",
    container: "#sortable-container",
    hint: function (element) { //this is not called and is messing with my karma coverage
        var elementHint = element.clone();

        elementHint.find('[ng-transclude=""]').removeAttr("ng-transclude");
        elementHint.find(".hw-closeable").removeClass("hw-closeable");

        return elementHint.addClass("sortable-tooltip");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing, calling the hint function manually was good enough for me. I agree that for integration tests something fancier is required.

My code looks like this:

**Directive**

```
angular.module('appSample').directive('sortableDiv', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'src/widgets/sortable-div/sortable-div.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $element.find("#sortable-container").kendoSortable({
                axis: "none",
                cursor: "move",
                container: "#sortable-container",
                hint: function (element) {
                    return element.clone().addClass("sortable-tooltip");
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Directive HTML**

```
<div id="sortable-container" class="row sortable-container" ng-transclude></div>
```

**Karma Test**

```
function sortableDiv() {
    var el = angular.element('<div sortable-div><div id="sort1">Sort me!</div> <div id="sort2">Sort me again!</div></div>');

    compile(el)(scope);

    scope.$digest();
    timeout.flush();

    return el;
}

it('should hint a sortable div', function () {

    var el = sortableDiv();

    var elHint = el.find("#sortable-container").data("kendoSortable").options.hint(el.find("#sort1"));

    expect(elHint.attr("class")).toContain("sortable-tooltip");
});
```